# Query taking 1781s -

Tags: php, mysql

I've spent a long time trying to work out why this query is killing my server:

```
# Query_time: 1781.559941  Lock_time: 0.000060 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 7576453128
SET timestamp=1460479284;
SELECT r.user
FROM questions q, results r
WHERE r.user = 0
AND r.user=q.user
GROUP BY q.user
LIMIT 1;
```

There are *9,891,888* records in `results` and maybe *7000* records in `questions`.

In my mind this doesn't make sense.

I have indexes set up on `user` in both tables.

Comment: use "on" while joining the two tables and check the time taken for the query to execute

Comment: So how much time have you spent doing an EXPLAIN on this query to see how it is being executed by MySQL?

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

[**MySQL**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view)

Comment: Which columns have an index?

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Comment: What are your indexes?

Comment: Wow thanks guys :D I didn't realise there was so many bad points to my query. Its 5 years old now.

Answer (score 1):

What is this query exactly for when you just fetch `r.user` ? Looks to me like you could achieve the same results with an `INNER JOIN` .

Answer (score 1):

I would try this... but you should try to look at the explain plan. I think the group by might cause a slowdown, so I took that out and put in normal join syntax. Also might want to look at the health of your index on the big table and make sure it's not fragmented (try rebuilding it)

```
SELECT r.user
FROM questions q inner join results r on r.user=q.user
WHERE r.user = 0
LIMIT 1;
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT `user` FROM `questions` 
INNER JOIN `results` 
ON `user`.`user`=`results`.`user` 
WHERE `user`.`user` = 0 
GROUP BY `user`.`user` 
LIMIT 1;
```

If don't work, can you write your create table for the table *user* and *questions*?